# Exception in Tkinter callback: IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am creating a GUI file using the Tkinter module to build a structure of the desktop application for a chatbot. However, I keep getting this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/bellacho/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "<ipython-input-3-466bf200dfb6>", line 70, in send
    res = getResponse(ints, intents)
  File "<ipython-input-3-466bf200dfb6>", line 49, in getResponse
    tag = ints[0]['intent']
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Any idea how to fix this? Please let me know, thank you in advance.
Here is my code:

```
def getResponse(ints, intents_json):
    tag = ints[0]['intent']
    list_of_intents = intents_json['intents']
    for i in list_of_intents:
        if(i['tag']== tag):
            result = random.choice(i['responses'])
            break
    return result

#Creating tkinter GUI
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

def send():
    msg = EntryBox.get("1.0",'end-1c').strip()
    EntryBox.delete("0.0",END)

    if msg != '':
        ChatBox.config(state=NORMAL)
        ChatBox.insert(END, "You: " + msg + '\n\n')
        ChatBox.config(foreground="#446665", font=("Verdana", 12 )) 
        ints = predict_class(msg)
        res = getResponse(ints, intents)
        

        ChatBox.insert(END, "Bot: " + res + '\n\n')           

        ChatBox.config(state=DISABLED)

        ChatBox.yview(END)

root = Tk()
root.title("Chatbot")
root.geometry("400x500")
root.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)
```

Comment: It looks like `ints` is empty

Comment: What does `predict_class(msg)` do? What is `ints`.

Answer (score 0):

ints is not a list so there is a problem with the `getResponse` function because you are treating it that way
try to remake the `getResponse` function
then see how you need to trit ints

Comment: If `ints` is not a list, it won't get `IndexError: list index out of range` error.  It will get something like `TypeError: 'xxx' object is not subscriptable` instead.